# Sending byte array from NodeJS to C library

Tags: c, node.js, ipc

I have a NodeJS server running on the same server with a C program. I need to sent a byte array from my NodeJS server to my C program. I have a set_title function in C.

```
set_title(uint16_t *title)
```

Any idea how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some form of interprocess communication to be able to do that.

There are libraries out there which can facilitate that work for you, have a look at [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org) and [zmq](http://zeromq.org) which both have both C and JS bindings.